# Using the solidify modifier with no deformed geometry

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I made a scaffolding out of planes. I'm trying to solidify it but it appears deformed. Here are my settings...
[image: settings]

10/10
[image]

How should I approach fixing this issue?

Comment: I decided to go about this in an awkward way which involved tri fold edges. I managed to fix this by individually solidifying each beam and repairing the intersections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got trifold edges, that is edges that belong to three faces.

Not only is that a bad modelling practice, that creates non manifold meshes, that could never really exist in real life.

That causes severe modelling and topology issues and will lead to trouble sooner or later, least of which are the ones you are encountering with the *Solidify* modifier.

Eliminate the trifold edges, either by erasing the faces and recreating them by duplicating an edge; or using the *Rip* operator and separating the duplicate edges.

Also make sure your *Solidify* has the *Even Thickness* option ticked

[image: Solidify Trifold]

Alternatively consider using bezier curve objects for this sort of work, they seem like a more adequate tool for this sort of structure.