# Is there a better method to add uniform thickness to a curve pattern that has been converted into a mesh?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, geometry, extrude

I have the following mesh with no thickness or faces:

[image: Original Mesh]

I wish to be able to apply a uniform thickness along with clean geometry without creating too many vertices.

The solidify modifier isn't getting me what I desire:

[image: Solidify -> Extrude]

The skin modifier is getting me closer to what I want, but I am unable to control the thickness of the object, generating extra geometry from what I need and creating undesirable faces and edges.

The process here is after the skin modifier is applied, the geometry is flattened on the Z axis, vertices doubles removed, and then extruded.

[image: Skin Modifier]
[image: Undesirable Geometry]
[image: Similar to what is desired]

There has to be a simpler, less computationally expensive and more flexible solution to this that I am unaware of.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using the solidify modifier with no deformed geometry](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74403/using-the-solidify-modifier-with-no-deformed-geometry)

Comment: You could also not convert to mesh and use built curve tools to bevel geometry

Comment: In my opinion this can be avoided if you create the path objects in a vector drawing program, That way you can create curves that have width you want instead of being a single line. Export as SVGs, import in blender and give the curve some extrusion.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there's a simpler way but you could try with the *Wireframe* modifier:

- Select your mesh, fill with <kbd>F</kbd>.
- Give your object a *Wireframe* modifier. Enable *Boundary*, choose the *Thickness* you want.
- Apply the modifier.
- In *Edit* mode, select all and flatten with a <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>.
- Remove doubles with a <kbd>W</kbd>.
- Delete the unwanted faces.
- Work the angles.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That's great, I'll book mark this and use this method from now on.