# Solidify weird behaviour - Not following face normals

Tags: modeling

[image]

I noticed that solidify doesn't follow the face normal and produce a weird result. You can see from the right ortho view that the vertices are not aligned with the original one. Any Idea? I already applied the transformations and recalculated the normals... 
To me it looks like the modifier only projects the vertices using x/y/z directions without accounting for the normals.

[Video showing the issue](https://youtu.be/BQROgPiRG7A)

I added a couple of pictures to show the desired result achieved with the skew tool.

[image: wire][image: Solid]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using the solidify modifier with no deformed geometry](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74403/using-the-solidify-modifier-with-no-deformed-geometry)

Comment: "*You can see from the right ortho view*" Where? We can't see anything

Comment: Do you see the red circles in the image? Those vertices should be on the same line. And is not a duplicate, the issue is different.

Comment: did you tick the even thickness checkbox? There's also the "high quality normals" option which seems to solve any issues that I have with the modifier.

Comment: Yes, no change...